# Is it possible to move text of foot line in beamer

Tags: beamer

Question:

In my slide when you compile, we can see that in foot-line there are three parts (Name , Title , date with page number). My question is Can we move our title from foot-line to head-line (which is already blank with 2 color combination)?

And my second question is can we achieve single color for foot-line as well as for head-line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usecolortheme{default}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer

\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif

%title
\author{Mr. X. Y. Z.}

\title{My Title}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t]{ABC}
        In this slide, i will write text related this title.        
        \[\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0\]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This kind of change is normally done in  beamed by changing or editing the so called `outertheme`.

Comment: This is possible to write the title in the upper bar. But the upper bars are supposed to hold the section and subsection titles. So you can do \section{The Title of my Presentation} and you get the presentation title in the upper bar. But this is somehow a misuse of the theme. Maybe, you can find a theme more adapted to your needs https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: @Alain Merigot if you make some necessary correction to my mwe it will be a great help to me

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `hackthefootline` package to configure which information should be in your footline and which should be removed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usecolortheme{default}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer

\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif

%title
\author{Mr. X. Y. Z.}

\title{My Title}

\date{\today}

\usepackage[onecol]{hackthefootline}
\htfconfig{%
    authinst=onlyauthor,
    date=long, 
    framenrs=fraction,
    title=none
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left,leftskip=1em]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\inserttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t]{ABC}
        In this slide, i will write text related this title.        
        \[\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0\]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]